# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I am getting following error

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed)**

while I try to fetch data from a text file using `$.post`
On first try web page works fine and data is loaded from file but when I refresh it is not loaded sometimes.When I deleted cache and try again it was loaded successfully.But still I think this problem is not because of cache only.First time when I loaded the page error was there showing in JS console.I am using **Google Chrome**.

```
<body>
    <div onclick="fetch_data()">click me</div>  
    <h1 class="result"></h1>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch_data()
        {
            $.post('sometext.txt', function(data) 
            {
                $('.result').html(data);
            });
        }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're browser is handling this POST the same as Safari is...
see: http://avnwx.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/debuggers-lie.html 
in my case this problem was solved by adding a timestamp to the URL of the linked file to stop my browser from pulling up the cached version.

Comment: yep, this is called a "cash-buster"

Comment: How to add timestamp to url?